# Is there a connection between the Chinese 鱼(fish, or yu) and ゆ(yu) looking like a fish?

Tags: chinese

I noticed this coincidence and I couldn't help wondering since other parts are based off of Chinese(kanji)

Comment: Note that the Chinese sound written as _yu_ is actually _ü_ in German ([[y]]) and not a set of a consonant and a vowel like _you_ in English and ゆ in Japanese.

Comment: Yeah, I know :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's a coincidence.  ゆ is over a thousand years old and is thought to be derived from 由.  You can find a chart of the kanji that hiragana developed from on [Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%B9%B3%E4%BB%AE%E5%90%8D).

Mandarin *yú* is more recent and corresponds to Japanese 魚 *gyo*, both of which developed from Middle Chinese *ngyo* (where the digraph ‹ng› represents the nasal velar sound [ŋ], as in English *ring*).  At the time ゆ developed, the sound was too different from *yu* to make this kind of connection.

Answer (score 2):

No.

Hiragana ゆ developed from the kanji character 由 (see for example [this](http://blog.livedoor.jp/gisui_shodo/archives/1028072260.html)).

Japanese on-yomi reading of kanji 魚 is ぎょ and there is no relation to the Chinese *yu*.